# When calling TransformProcessType(), the app menu doesn't show up

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

If you call TransformProcessType() like this :

```
ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0, kCurrentProcess }; 
(void) TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);
```

Then the cocoa app menu doesn't show up unless you call this early enough in your app (eg. in applicationWillFinishLaunching).

Comment: I got the answer but because my reputation is too low I can only answer it within 8 hours. I'll try adding a comment already.

Comment: I asked Apple for help and they helped me very well. Quote :

> The reason why the menu bar isn't show when you call TransformProcessType is that your app is already the active app (that is, [[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] isActive] returns YES) and the menu bar for an app is shown when the app is *activated*

Comment: This is their workaround :

        - (void)transformStep1 {
        for (NSRunningApplication * app in [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.finder"]) {
            [app activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
            break;
        }
        [self performSelector:@selector(transformStep2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }

Comment: - (void)transformStep2
    {
        ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0, kCurrentProcess }; 
        (void) TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);
    
        [self performSelector:@selector(transformStep3) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }
    
    - (void)transformStep3
    {
        [[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
    }

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I asked Apple for help and they helped me very well. Quote :

> The reason why the menu bar isn't show when you call TransformProcessType is that your app is already the active app (that is, [[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] isActive] returns YES) and the menu bar for an app is shown when the app is *activated*

This is their workaround :

```
- (void)transformStep1 {
    for (NSRunningApplication * app in [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.finder"]) {
        [app activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
        break;
    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(transformStep2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

- (void)transformStep2
{
    ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0, kCurrentProcess }; 
    (void) TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);

    [self performSelector:@selector(transformStep3) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

- (void)transformStep3
{
    [[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
}
```

Comment: I have used @"com.apple.dock". That seems better than activating Finder causing it to jump to foreground.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I made it working.

```
BOOL MakeAppForeground()
{
    BOOL bSuccess = TranformAppToState(kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);

    if(bSuccess)
    {
         bSuccess = (SetSystemUIMode(kUIModeNormal, 0) == 0);
        [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    }

    return bSuccess;
}

BOOL MakeAppBackground()
{
    return TranformAppToState(kProcessTransformToBackgroundApplication);
}

BOOL TranformAppToState(ProcessApplicationTransformState newState)
{
    ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0, kCurrentProcess };
    OSStatus transformStatus = TransformProcessType(&psn, newState);

    if((transformStatus != 0))
    {
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:transformStatus userInfo:nil];
        NSLog(@"TranformAppToState: Unable to transform App state. Error - %@",error);
    }

    return (transformStatus == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, which is triggered on checkbox click in Preferences window. The only side effect is short flashing of the app's windows:

```
- (void) hideDockIcon:(bool) hide
{
    ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0, kCurrentProcess };
    ProcessApplicationTransformState state = hide ? kProcessTransformToUIElementApplication : kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication;
    OSStatus err = TransformProcessType(&psn, state);
    
    if (err) {
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:err userInfo:nil];
        NSLog(@"TransformProcessType failed: %@", error);
    }
}

- (void) toggleDockIcon
{
    [NSApp hide:self];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self hideDockIcon:self.preferences.hideDockIcon];
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
        });
    });
}
```